# Searching through a JSON File

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, discord.js

Imagine I have a JSON-file:

```
{
   "something": {
      "hey":      "15145143",
      "foo":      "32431451",
      "test":     "34131343",
      "anything": "12341123"
   }
}
```

The names shouldn't matter, only their values.
Now I have a String s, and I want to know if this string is a value of my json-file.
I imagine something like, but apparently this command doesn't exists:

```
if (file.something.includes(s)) ...
```

Comment: Can we assume that you already parsed the the JSON in the file and assigned the result to `file`? Since that is what it looks like in your sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
if (Object.values(file.something).includes(s))
```

by using [`object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) method, you are querying only your object values

```js
const obj = {
   "something": {
      "hey":      "15145143",
      "foo":      "32431451",
      "test":     "34131343",
      "anything": "12341123"
   }
}

console.log('Does object include 15145143?', Object.values(obj.something).includes('15145143'));

console.log('Does object include 123?', Object.values(obj.something).includes('123'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the string exactly to the values then use

```
stringToMatch = 's'
console.log(Object.values(yourJson.something).includes(stringToMatch ))
```

If you want it to match sub-strings of values then use

```
stringToMatch = 's'
console.log(Object.values(yourJson.something).some(key => key.includes(stringToMatch)))
```